# Finding Probability that Maximum Value of $N + 1$ Random Variables is Larger than a Given Limit

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

For positive random variables $X_{0}, X_{1}, X_{2}, \ldots, X_{N}$, where $N$ is also a random variable, we know that $X_{1}, X_{2}, \ldots, X_{N - 1}$ are I.I.D. with continuous PDF $f(x)$ and $X_{0} + X_{1} + X_{2} + \ldots + X_{N} = 1$. What is $P(\max_{i = 0} ^ {N} X_{i} \le d)$, for a given $d$?

If an exact solution is not possible, can one find bounds for this probability? Can this problem be solved if $f(x)$ is some well-known distribution (say exponential, log-normal, etc.)?

**EDIT.** An equivalent problem is this: a number of points lie in the interval $[0, 1]$. If we know that the length of segments between each two consecutive points are I.I.D random variables with PDF $f(x)$ (this does NOT include the distance between $0$ and the first point, or $1$ and the last point), what is the probability that there is no opening larger than $d$ in this interval? $d$ is a given and fixed parameter.

**EDIT2.** A related problem may be this: for a 1-D point process spanning $\mathbb{R}$ where interarrival times are I.I.D. random variables with PDF $f(x)$, what is the probability of observing an opening bigger that a given value $d$ in the interval $[0, 1]$? The spaces between $0$ and the first point falling in the interval and $1$ and the last point falling in the interval count as well. For example, if for some realization there is only one point in the interval $[0, 1]$ at $\frac{1}{2}$, there are two openings in this interval and both have a length of $0.5$. If for some other realization there are no points in the interval $[0, 1]$, there is only one opening in this interval and it has a length of $1$.

Hope this edit clears up the confusion and does not add to it.

Comment: What do we know about the distribution of $N$?

Comment: Please proofread your question. Is n=N? Max of X_i?

Comment: @zoli no information about the distribution of $N$.

Comment: @YuvalPeres corrected, thanks!

Comment: What are the distributions of $X_0$ and $X_N$?

Comment: @TMM unknown. The only thing we know is that the sum adds up to 1.

Comment: The requirement the first $N-1$ variables are iid and $X_N$ is not (actually, it's determined by the others) sounds weird, artificial ... probably wrong. And it doesn't look "equivalent" at all to the problem of your last paragraph (you hadn't stated that $X_i$ need to be positive, among many things). Perhaps a better model is : take $Y_1, Y_2 \cdots Y_N$ iid, non-negative and let $X_i = Y_i/\sum(Y_i)$ , etc

Comment: Goodarz, are you interested in a numerical approximation?  If $f(x)$ is piecewise polynomial, then $g(d) = P(M<d)$ appears to be piecewise polynomial, and it is does not appear to be too entirely difficult to get an exact expression for $g(d)$.

Comment: @leonbloy It seems to me you are ignoring $X_{0}$ for some reason. Also, the first sentence mentions "positive random variables". Any other reasons why the two problems are not equivalent?

Comment: @irchans Definitely! That would be really helpful.

Comment: @GoodarzMehr   Alright, I will have a bit of time this weekend, so I will work on some numerical approximation schemes.  The coolest one would be exactly correct expressions for $g(d) = P(N<d)$ when $f$ is piecewise polynomial.  Hopefully, some young energetic mathematician will beat me to it !

Answer (score 1):

The problem is underspecified by *a lot*...  We know almost nothing about $X_0, X_N$ and $N$ except that the three of them together contrive to make $\sum_{j=0}^N X_j = 1$.

For shorthand, write $M = \max_{j=0}^N X_j.$

Obviously $M \le 1$, so $\forall d \ge 1: P(M \le d) = 1$.  This is trivial and from now on we only consider $d < 1$.

**Claim A:** No non-trivial (i.e. $> 0$) lower bound is possible.  I.e. there exists an example where $\forall d < 1: P(M \le d) = 0$.

Example A: $N \equiv 0, X_0 \equiv X_N \equiv 1$.  In this example $M \equiv 1$, so $\forall d < 1: P(M \le d) = 0$.

**Claim B:** If $d \ge \frac12$, no non-trivial (i.e. $<1$) upper bound is possible.  I.e. there exists an example where $\forall d \ge \frac12: P(M \le d) = 1$.

Example B: $N \equiv 1, X_0 \equiv X_N \equiv \frac12$.  In this case $M \equiv \frac12$, so $\forall d \ge \frac12: P(M \le d) = 1$.

**Claim C:** If $d < \frac12$, a possibly non-trivial upper bound is $P(M \le d) \le P(X_1 \le d) = F(d)$ where $F()$ is the CDF of $X_1$.

Proof: We are free to pick $X_0, X_N$ as high as desired subject to each being $\le d$, but this leaves a "gap" of at least $1-2d > 0$, which must be filled by at least $X_1$.  For $M\le d$ to happen requires $X_1 \le d$.  Thus $P(M \le d) \le P(X_1 \le d) = F(d)$.

**Claim D:** (Stronger version of Claim C) If $d < \frac12$, a possibly non-trivial upper bound is $P(M \le d) \le F(d)^K$ where $K = \lceil {1-2d \over d} \rceil = \lceil {\frac1d - 2} \rceil$.

Proof: Refining the above proof, if a gap of size at least $1-2d$ is to be filled by one or more $X_j$'s, and each $X_j \le d$, then the number of such $X_j$'s must be $\ge K = \lceil {1-2d \over d} \rceil$.  For $M \le d$ to happen therefore requires at least all of $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_K \le d$.  Since they are I.I.D., $P(\text{all } X_1, \dots, X_k \le d) = F(d)^K$.

**Claim E:** For any particular value of $d$ (where $d < \frac12$), the bound in Claim D is tight.  I.e. there exists an example (dependent on $d$) where $P(M \le d) = F(d)^K$.

Example E: $X_0 = d, N = K+1, X_N = 1 - (K+1)d,$ and $X_j$ is bi-valued (biased coin flip) and takes value $d$ with probability $F(d)$ and some other value $c > d$ with probability $1 - F(d)$.  Then $M \le d$ happens iff you get $K$ coin flips of value $d$ each, i.e. $P(M \le d) = F(d)^K$.

---

I imagine better bounds are possible if we have more info, e.g. to eliminate/disallow Examples A and B.  Or even just in Claim D/E, a better bound might be possible if we know the behavior of $F()$ at small values, to eliminate Example E.

Comment: $X_{0}, X_{N}, N$ are also random variables and the probability should be calculated over all of them. You can't set them to some value and calculate the probability over the rest of random variables.

Comment: But you didnt specify what they are...  so I give examples, where they are constants, to show various bounds.   Did you mean $X_0$ has a pdf $f_0$ and $N$ has a pmf $p_N$ and $X_N$ has a pdf $f_N$?  And how are they related?  They are certainly not mutually independent since everything together sums to $1$.  Even in your EDIT, the situation remains underspecified.  What is the process that generates the points s.t. the inter-point gaps are IID with pdf $f$?  Your EDIT doesn't rule out e.g. $X_0$ being a constant.

Comment: I did specify they are RVs in a general sense, and left the notation to the reader. Whether I specify the PDF of $X_{0}$ is called $f_{0}$ or not does not change the problem. Yes, you can assume $X_{0}$ is constant, but that would just be a special case.
Let me give you an example. If $f(x)$ is exponential, it follows that the points come from a PPP, which in turn means that the PMF of $N$ is Poisson and the PDF of $X_{0}$ and $X_{N}$ are both exponential. I know this is a special case, but I think even in the general case $f(x)$ would be enough to deduce other distribution functions from.

Comment: OK, I understand.  In that case, Claim D is still of value, since that is an upperbound that is valid regardless of $X_0, X_N, N$.  What my claims A,B,E show is that, unless you further specify $X_0, X_N, N$, it is not possible to get good bounds.

Comment: BTW, it is actually impossible that $f(x)$ is exponential, because we know $X_1 < 1$ but the exponential r.v. can be any value $[0, \infty]$.

Comment: Or $N = 0$ in that case

Comment: that's exactly what i mean:  if $f(x)$ were exponential, then $N = 0$ and so $f(x)$ doesnt matter.  whereas if $N > 0$, then $f(x)$ cannot be exponential.  there is _no_ joint probability space for $(X_0, X_j, X_N, N)$ for which both $P(N>0)>0$ and $f(x) = $ exponential, see?  The very fact that $P(X_1 > 1) = 0$ means it is not exponential.